# heller functor of finite order

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Hi,
let A be a finite dimensional selfinjective algebra.
Assume mod A is periodic.That is for every finite dimensional module with no projective summand we have: $ \Omega^{n} (M) =M $ for some n ,where $ \Omega $ is the Hellerfunctor(giving the kernel of a projective cover of M ).
When is it true that $ \Omega $ is of finite order,that is $ \Omega^{n} $ is isomorphic as a functor to the identity functor of the stable category of modules ?(Assume there is a common biggest period for all module if necassary)

Thanks for help

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think $\Omega$ is well-defined on the category of modules without projective summands (since it isn't well defined on homomorphisms as far as I can see). You might want to consider replacing that by the stable module category. 

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, this is an open problem.  There are no known examples where $\mbox{mod-}A$ is periodic (say, with a common period $n$ for all modules), but $\Omega^n$ is not isomorphic to the identity functor on the stable category.  In fact, $\mbox{mod-}A$ being periodic may well imply that $A$ is a *periodic algebra*, meaning that $A$ has a periodic projective resolution as a module over its enveloping algebra.  This is another open question.  Examples where this happens include the preprojective algebras of Dynkin type and generalized Dynkin type, and their deformations [K. Erdmann, A. Skowronski.  Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 359 (2007), no. 6, 2625--2650], and all self-injective algebras of finite representation type [J. Pure Appl. Algebra 214 (2010), no. 6, 990–1000].

One class of examples where $\mbox{mod-}A$ is periodic, but it is not known (at least to me) whether $\Omega$ has finite order or not, is the so-called *higher preprojective algebras* studied by O. Iyama and S. Oppermann [arXiv:0912.3412v1].  Here, I believe the problem is connected to the question of whether the Nakayama automorphism has finite order.

Answer (score 5):

Another example: If $A$ is a bialgebra over a field $k$ then $\Omega^n(k) = k$ implies $\Omega^n = id$.

The proof is rather simple: Choose a projective resolution $P \to k$ such that $\Omega^i(k)$ is the kernel of $P_{i-1} \to P_{i-2}$.  Since $M$ is $k$-projective, 
$$P \otimes_k M\to k \otimes_k M \cong M$$ is a projective resolution of $M$ where $A$ acts diagonally on the tensor product (that's the place were the bialgebra structure is needed). If $f: M \to N$ is $A$-linear, then we obtain a commutative diagramm with exact rows 
$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & \to & M & \cong & k \otimes M & \to & P_{n-1} \otimes M & \to P_{n-2} \otimes M & \to \cdots  \newline
  &     & \scriptstyle f\; \displaystyle \downarrow &  & \scriptstyle id \otimes f\;\displaystyle\downarrow & & \scriptstyle id \otimes f\; \displaystyle\downarrow   & \scriptstyle id \otimes f\; \displaystyle \downarrow\newline  
0 & \to & N & \cong & k \otimes N & \to & P_{n-1} \otimes N & \to P_{n-2} \otimes N & \to \cdots  \newline
\end{array}$$
Since up to a projective summand $\Omega^n(M)$ is just the kernel in a projective resolution, we have $$M = \Omega^n(M) \oplus(\text{projective}) \text{ and }f = \Omega^n(f) \oplus p,$$
i.e. $\Omega^n(M) = M$ and $\Omega^n(f) = f$ in the stable category. Thus $\Omega^n = id$.

**Note**: If $k$ is a commutative ring and $A$ projective as $k$-module then the same proof shows $\Omega^n = id$ on the stable category of finitely generated, $k$-projective $A$-modules.

Answer (score 3):

I can show that the claim is true if $A$ is defined over $\mathbb F_{p^\infty}$, the algebraic closure of the field with $p$ elements. This proof will unfortunately not generalize to arbitrary algebraically closed fields (not even such of characteristic $p$), nor will it bound the exponent $n$ such that $\Omega^n \cong \rm id$ in any useful way. It does however show that it suffices to  know that each simple module is periodic in order to conclude that $\Omega^n\cong \rm id$ for some $n$ (again, of course, only for algebras over $\mathbb F_{p^\infty}$).

Fix $n\in\mathbb N$  such that 
$\Omega^{n}(S) \cong S$ for any simple $A$-module $S$.

All but the last paragraph is the same as Theorem 2.5 in *K. Erdmann and A. Skowronski. Periodic algebras. Trends in Representation Theory and Related Topics. European Math.
Soc., Zurich, 2008.* (you can view the relevant parts of this on google books).

First choose a projective cover $P$ of $_A A_A$ (i.e., $P$ is a projective $A$-$A$-bimodule). Then choose an $A$-$A$-bimodule $X$ as the kernel of the epimorphism from $P$ to $A$, i.e. we get a s.e.q. of $A$-$A$-bimdoules
$$
  0 \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow P \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow 0
$$
As a sequence of left or right $A$-modules this sequence is split, hence $X$ is projective as a left and as a right $A$-module. This implies that tensoring the above sequence with any (left or right) $A$-module will again yield an exact sequence of left $A$-modules, with projective middle term (since $P\otimes_A M$ is projective for any $A$-module $M$). This shows that
$-\otimes_A X$ is isomorphic to $\Omega(-)$ on the stable module category.  Now $-\otimes_AX$ is a stable auto-equivalence of Morita-type, and so is $-\otimes_A X^{\otimes n}$. The latter sends simple modules to themselves, and therefore lifts to a Morita auto-equivalence, w.l.o.g. induced by the $A$-$A$-bimodule $Y$ (the fact that stable equivalences of Morita type which send simple modules to simple modules lift to Morita equivalences is usually attributed to Linckelmann). That is, $-\otimes_A Y \cong \Omega^n(-)$ on the stable module category. In particular $S\otimes_A Y \cong S$ for all simple $A$-modules $S$. But any Morita-autoequivalence which sends simple modules to themselves is induced by an automorphism $\alpha$ of $A$, i.e. $Y$ is isomorphic to the twisted $A$-$A$-bimodule $_{id} A_{\alpha}$.

Now comes the ugly part which doesn't work over arbitrary fields: $\alpha: A \longrightarrow A$ must have finite order, since every non-zero element in $\mathbb F_{p^\infty}$ is a root of unity and therefore every invertible matrix over $\mathbb F_{p^\infty}$ has finite order ( ${\rm Aut}(A) \leq {\rm GL}(A)$, and ${\rm GL}(A)$ is a torsion group). Hence there is some $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $Y^{\otimes m} \cong {_AA_A}$. But then 
$$\Omega^{m\cdot n}(-)\cong -\otimes_A Y^{\otimes m} \cong -\otimes_A {_{id} A _{\alpha^m}} \cong \rm id$$